# inverse_of does not works inside after_initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

inverse_of seems does not works inside after_initialize callback

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :faces, :inverse_of => :user
end

class Face < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :faces
  after_initialize :init

  def init
    p user.object_id
  end
end

u = User.find(56)
u.object_id
 => 70242500754120 

u.faces.first.user.object_id
  Face Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `faces`.* FROM `faces` WHERE `faces`.`user_id` = 56 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 56 LIMIT 1
70242477010060
 => 70242500754120 

u.faces.first.user == u
 => true
```

inside callback there is different objects, but outside is the same.
Looks like callback called before inverse_of magic has been set.

Any suggest for workaround, which allow access same object inside after_initialize callback ?
Thank you

Comment: Can you include a code snippet where it doesn't work? I'm looking for something like: `f = Face.new` or where you expect this callback to work.

Comment: @burninggramma `u.faces` is the place where it does not work: the `#faces` association method instantiates a `Face` instance for each associated record.

Answer (score 0):

The init method is actually fetching the user object from the database and returning it again.

Everytime you initialize a face, the application will ask the DB for the user, instantiate it, print the object_id... and forget it.

I'd recomend to use [eager loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) of user with a scope:

```
class Face
  belongs_to :user

  scope :with_user, -> { joins(:user) }
end
```

This will save you calls to the database :)